# Magento hide out of stock products

Tags: magento-1.7

I have `System->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Display Out of Stock Products` option set to `No`.

But this out-of-stock products still exist in category list. Is this config option works with product collection? How can i hide out-of-stock products from category product collections?

Comment: You may need to rebuild your indexes. (System->Index Management)

Answer (score 2):

To make this work you should go to `System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog` and set `Use Flat Catalog Product` to `Yes`. After that just launch `Product Flat Index`